# How to make a collapsable bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a fixed-top navbar that will collapse/fold as the user scrolls down, and will reappear/unfold the instant they scroll up even if they're at the bottom of the page.

I'm not even sure where to begin with this. Here's the basic layout I'm experimenting with:

http://jsfiddle.net/pp5dLdxw/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="padding-top:70px;">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">foo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="height:900px;">bar</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to achieve? Maybe I can understand it better

Comment: @KRUKUSA I'll try. It's tough because collapse technically means "horizontal resizing", where I mean more like how the Windows taskbar can auto-hide. I'll keep looking around.

Comment: there are lots and lots of tutorials on using scroll events to affect the DOM...Do some research. This question amounts to asking others to do this for you. You haven't even provided any expected behavior to go on. Please review help section on how to ask questions and what not to ask ...this definitely resides in the `what not to ask` category

Comment: @charlietfl I was very specific and spent quite some time providing as minimal and accurate a fiddle and code as I could to help others see what I was working with. I described what I'm trying to do exactly. What makes you think I was looking for someone to do it for me? I'm new to web design and this is the first place I look for info and found nothing. Doesn't that qualify as exactly the kind of question which should be asked?

Comment: not when 15 minutes later ( and some research effort) you come up with a solution

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your help. Now the answer is on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Found https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-autohidingnavbar

With some really simple steps to set it up:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="dist/jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.min.js"></script>

$(".navbar-fixed-top").autoHidingNavbar({
  // see next for specifications
});
```